# SVN CheckOut Issue - creating unwanted subfolder

Tags: ubuntu, svn, svn-checkout

I am using an SVN client installed on my hostgator account.  When I perform the following command:

```
svn co http://dev.server.com/proj/trunk/ --username myusername
```

The files are properly moved over from the SVN server on my local machine except for one thing.  Instead of being able to access the website like http:// stage.foo.com/ I have to access it like http:// stage.foo.com/trunk/ this is not good for what I am doing and need to be able to access it like http:// stage.foo.com/. (not the space after http:// is only because the spam preventer went off).

Is this because my svn directory structure looks like this:
/var/svn/proj/
/var/svn/proj/trunk
/var/svn/proj/branches
/var/svn/proj/tags

When I did svnadmin create it did it on /var/svn/proj/ should I have done this on /var/svn/proj/trunk/ instead?  I am new to SVN, please advise so I can resolve this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
svn co http://dev.server.com/proj/trunk/ /var/www/mysite --username myusername
```

or:

```
svn co http://dev.server.com/proj/trunk/ . --username myusername
```

The "." tells it to extract into the current directory, if you make sure you're in the right directory first.

Also, if you are using SVN to do releases, and by that I mean you will NOT be modifying the files on the server -- I assume you have a development/test site where you will be doing your coding, right? If that's the case then you should use `svn export` instead of `svn co` when you're doing your release.

The latter, for "checkout", will create a hidden .svn directory that keeps track of modified files so you can check them back in. Export copies just the current version of the files, with no extra data.

Comment: Yeah I used my home pc as a dev and a hostgator account as a staging server. This worked except I had to add --force for some reason.  Thank you for the tip on export vs checkout.

Answer (score 0):

with svn check out you can checkout first is your repsitory address and it protocle and second param is a destination and if not determin, mean current direcotry

```
 svn checkout  https://server.example.com/srv/svn/agaric  myworkingcopyfolder
```